# Sequelize. SQLite Type checking

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I started using **Sequelize** with **SQLite**. When I try to insert or update a value, it doesn't check for type-errors. For example I can use **string** values in a column with **sequelize.BOOLEAN** type.

I know [**SQLite** allows this](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q3), but what about  **Sequelize**? It doesn't check or I am missing something?

Should I add a validation check for each datatype? Is there an easy way of checking types instead of validating one by one in every model?

Comment: Did you find any solution to the same? Or any other alternative ORM could be used to achieve the same.?

Comment: No, not really. But I updated the answer and explained what I did. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, nobody answered this question, I write my own solution:

In `Sequelize` with `SQLite`, type checking is not enforced by default due to the nature of `SQLite`. However, you can add type validation at the `Sequelize` level.

Here’s an example of how to add a type validation for a `boolean` field:

```js
SOME_FIELD_VALIDATOR: {
  isIn: {
     args: [['true', 'false', true, false, 1, 0, '1', '0']],
     msg: 'Not a valid boolean.'
  }
}
```

In this example, the `isIn` validator checks if the value of the field is in the specified array. If the value is not in the array, it returns the message `'Not a valid boolean'`.

You can add similar validators for other data types as well. For instance, for an integer field, you could use the `isInt` validator.